# mySQL phpmyadmin - lowercase data by default

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know there are mySQL commands to convert database data to lowercase, but is there a way to create a field that automatically converts submitted data to lowercase / underscores by default when it is submitted? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: You could use an 'before insert' trigger on the tables/fields you want lowercased to dynamically rewrite particular fields with lower-cased data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use triggers for this purpose: [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)