# Forcing a field in a MySQL table to be lower-case

Tags: mysql

I have the field below in a MySQL table.  How can I force it to be in lower-case letters only?

```
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL phpmyadmin - lowercase data by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143962/mysql-phpmyadmin-lowercase-data-by-default)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL automatic conversion on lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795021/mysql-automatic-conversion-on-lowercase)

Answer (score 4):

In the database use the MySQL [`LOWER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) function around the inserts and/or the retrieval. You could also consider just doing it on the application side (meaning you still store the original...

Example

`INSERT INTO mytable (username) VALUES(LOWER('TestUser'))`

`SELECT LOWER(username) FROM mytable`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an 'before insert' trigger on the field you want to lowercased.
More infos here : [MySQL Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

(possible duplicate from here : [mySQL phpmyadmin - lowercase data by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143962/mysql-phpmyadmin-lowercase-data-by-default))

Comment: Next time, you may [flag the question as duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Rather then implementing it at application level you could write a database trigger that would change the content of the insert/update to lowercase as and when the insert/update happens, independent of the application.